# c# split string only if delimiter found

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

```
string search = "Apple : 100";

string[] result = search .Split(':');
```

Works fine with below output:

```
result[0] ==> Apple
result[1] ==> 100
```

But for this:

```
string search  = "Apple";    
string[] result = search .Split(':');
```

Outputs:

```
result[0] ==> Apple
```

Why the output is Apple ? I Just want empty array if the delimiter is missing in the search `string`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And why wouldn't you check for the delimiter before splitting? The question title is the obvious answer...

Comment: Because this is the way `string.Split()` works? https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "Why the output is Apple ?" Because that is the result most people would expect. Throwing away the only entry just because there is no second or third one is not a standard use case.

Comment: You can split `string` only if it contains your delimiter.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The way `String.Split` works is by returning an array with the split segments. If the delimiter is not present then there is only one segment - the entire string. From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___) (under *Return value details*):

> If this instance does not contain any of the strings in separator, the returned array consists of a single element that contains this instance.

To do what you want you can do:

```
var result = search.Contains(':') ? search.Split(':') : new string[0];
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't think about this solution. But how did you pick the sentence so fast from docs ?

Comment: @stom - I know it behaves like that :) so looked to find the evidence haha

Answer (score 0):

If string does not contains character which used as a delimiter, then it returns an array containing entire string as a array element. 
In your case, string `Apple`, does not contains delimiter. that is the reason, array contains **entire string** i.e. Apple as a zeroth element

Reference: [MSDN Spit() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)